# Using each cell in a range within a formula and returning the result in the same cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I suppose this should be easy, but - how do I extract a value from each cell in a range, place that value in a formula, and return the result in the same cell that the original value came from?
Example: (simplified :-))
I already have values entered in a range (say A1:A3): `A1=2.1 ; A2=0.78 ; A3=1.1`. I also have a specific factor in D1 e.g. D1=0.4, and a specific formula that I want to use: `exp(ln(value)/factor)`. What I want to do is:

1. extract the value in `A1 (=2.1)` and
2. place it in the formula together with the factor in `D1 (=exp(ln(2.1)/0.4))`
3. and put the result back in `A1 (=6.39)`

...and so on for `A2 (=0.54), A3 (=1.27)`......

As my range is very large, covering several sheets, I´m thinking some kind of "for each cell in range(myRange)" function, but I haven´t been able to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, try the following:

`Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range`

Then set your `Range`:

`Set rng = Range("A1:A3")`

Then begin your `For Each` loop:

```
For Each Cell In rng  
     Cell = Exp(Log(Cell)/Range("D4"))
Next Cell
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis. Also, you are declaring `rng` as a `Variant`. To fix, change to: `Dim rng as Range, Cell As Range`.

Comment: You're welcome. There are probably faster ways to do this with arrays, but you've provided what the OP asked for, so +1.

Comment: I knew it was an easy one ;-)